# How to assign regular strings for quarterly and monthly observation labels to the row names of a data frame?

Tags: r, label

[added since 150 chs restriction in the title]: "without having to enter all the dates of relevant data?"

**Reproducible Example:**

```
df <- data.frame(Col1=c(seq(1,50)), Col2=c(seq(51,100)))
df   # show data frame
row.names(df) <-  1965:2014
# Assigning for years is easy. Here, it is from 1965 to 2014; 50 years
df   # now, row names are assigned years
```

Assume I wanna assign regular quarters/months [2002:Q3-2014:Q4; 2010:11-2014:12 for months] instead of years.
Again, there are 50 row names (50 assignments) in case of quarters/months.
The separators are not important. "2002.3-2014.4", "2002:3-2014:4", etc. for quarters are all OK.

**What I tried and found** (which is very ugly):

```
library(gsubfn)
row.names(df) <- gsubfn("I.*", list(`I` = 1, `II` = 2, `III` = 3, `IV` = 4), c("2002-III", "2002-IV", "2003-I", "2003-II", "2003-III", "2003-IV", "2004-I", "2004-II", ... I wrote all the dates in between till , "2014-IV"))
```

Which uses some replacement that is even unnecessary:

```
row.names(df) <- c("2002.3", "2002.4",...,"2014.4")
```

will do even the same thing.

What I want is a solution that will not require all the dates in between; some short way as in years.

Comment: It is not clear for me.  For example `row.names(df)[1:3]
[1] "1965" "1966" "1967"`.  Can you tell what will be the replacement string here?  Are you assigning the quarters based on the `column` values?

Comment: The replacement is totally unnecessary. See my edit in question. Just assign 50 regular string for quarters/months. Based on nothing (i.e. not based on); assign just 50 regular time points.

Comment: Can you show what will be first three rownames?

Comment: For quarters: "2002.3, 2002.4, 2003.1" or "2002:3,2002:4,2003:1" or "2002Q3, 2002Q4, 2003Q1" whatever you wish. For months:"2010.11,2010.12,2011.1" or ""2010:11,2010:12,2011:1" or "2010.M11,2010.M12,2011.M1" or "2010M11,2010M12,2011M1" or "2010M11,2010M12,2011M01" whatever you wish. Just 50 regular strings to express quarters/months and their assigning to row names without having to write all (50) of them. In years, we wrote/used only 2 years, and it sufficed to assign 50 years. Just something like that.

Comment: I liked both of the solutions of Steven Beaupre and Steven. However, the SOF system does not allow me to choose both as answers. Anyway, I thank very much for both of you. I think both of the solutions will be used frequently in future by some others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what I understand from your question, you could do:

```
library(lubridate)
row.names(df) <- as.yearqtr(seq(ymd('1965-01-01'), by = '1 quarter', length.out=(50)))
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with `yearqtr` in zoo and `as.roman` from R:

```
library(zoo)

qtrs <- seq(as.yearqtr("2002q3"), length = nrow(df), by = 1/4)
row.names(df) <-  paste(format(qtrs, "%Y"), as.roman(format(qtrs, "%q")), sep = "-")
```

giving:

```
> head(row.names(df))
[1] "2002-III" "2002-IV"  "2003-I"   "2003-II"  "2003-III" "2003-IV"
```

**Note 1:** If its not important that roman numerals be used then the it can be shortened to:

```
row.names(df) <- seq(as.yearqtr("2002q3"), length = nrow(df), by = 1/4)
```

giving:

```
> head(row.names(df))
[1] "2002 Q3" "2002 Q4" "2003 Q1" "2003 Q2" "2003 Q3" "2003 Q4"
```

**Note 2:** Since this is a time series you might want to use a time series representation in the first place rather than a data.frame so that you can use other time series operations on it.  In that case:

```
library(zoo)
z <- zooreg(df, start = as.yearqtr("2002q3"), freq = 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

To create just the strings you need, you could also do:

```
    x <- rep(seq(2002, 2014, 1), 4)
    x <- sort(x)
    y <- rep(seq(1, 4, 1), 12)
    rows <- paste(x, y, sep = ".")

    > rows
    [1] "2002.1" "2002.2" "2002.3" "2002.4" "2003.1" "2003.2" "2003.3" "2003.4"
    [9] "2004.1" "2004.2" "2004.3" "2004.4" "2005.1" "2005.2" "2005.3" "2005.4"
    [17] "2006.1" "2006.2" "2006.3" "2006.4" "2007.1" "2007.2" "2007.3" "2007.4"
    [25] "2008.1" "2008.2" "2008.3" "2008.4" "2009.1" "2009.2" "2009.3" "2009.4"
    [33] "2010.1" "2010.2" "2010.3" "2010.4" "2011.1" "2011.2" "2011.3" "2011.4"
    [41] "2012.1" "2012.2" "2012.3" "2012.4" "2013.1" "2013.2" "2013.3" "2013.4"
    [49] "2014.1" "2014.2" "2014.3" "2014.4"
```